# Get a Dom element from website using php

Tags: php, html, curl, dom, domdocument

Hello guys I want to get an HTML node from website to show it in my website, but I can't do it.

### This is my code.

```
$html = htmlentities(file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$h1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
var_dump($h1);
```

### And this is the result.

```
object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be calling `htmlentities`. `DOMDocument` expects you to load the original HTML, not the HTML converted to entities.

Comment: Because this code
`$doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML("http://stackoverflow.com/");
 $h1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;
 print_r($h1);`
gives me Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to apply `htmlentities` on an html string before to parse it. If you do that, all angle brackets are replaced and the parser will no more find any tags.

There's also no need to use `file_get_contents` to load a file, since `DOMDocument` has a method to do it.

In your comment, you didn't use the good method to load an HTML file with its URL (and not an HTML string).

The `DOMDocument` method is `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` and not `DOMDocument::loadHTML`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://stackoverflow.com/");
$h1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;
echo $h1, PHP_EOL;
```

Note that you can prevent the different warnings to be displayed using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before this method.

Comment: Thank you very much Can you recommend any document or website to me to know more about this topic?!! and what is the best methodology to use in php to get a web page content?!!!